# Как починить KeyError: key при попытки верификации почты в django-allauth?

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь прикрутить верификацию по e-mail к своему проекту на Django 2.2.1 + rest_framework. 
Для аутентификации использую rest_auth, который в свою очередь использует django-allauth.
При регистрации нового юзера, письмо отправляется корректно (вернее имитируется при помощи `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`)

Однако при переходе по ссылке получаю исключение с вот таким трейсбеком:

```
Internal Server Error: /account-confirm-email/MTU:1hdYJH:vsf9c1crzBoGBa70De731JG67eI/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 270, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\kotov_or\django_envs\IRM\envIRM\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 341, in get_object
    key = self.kwargs['key']
KeyError: 'key'
[19/Jun/2019 16:04:17] "GET /account-confirm-email/MTU:1hdYJH:vsf9c1crzBoGBa70De731JG67eI/ HTTP/1.1" 500 97649
```

Вот мои urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
     name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
     name='account_confirm_email')
]
```

Вот мои settings.py (в том, что касается вопроса)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vk',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',
]

SITE_ID = 1
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True #Без этой опции результат тот же, подрубил ради теста
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

Файлы библиотек не трогал, классы не переназначал. Всё в дефолтных значениях.

Вот список версий связанных библиотек, на всякий случай:

```
django-allauth==0.39.1
Django==2.2.1
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.9.4
oauthlib==3.0.1
```

Я не прошу написать за меня (хотя был бы рад, ха ха). Но я никак не могу понять на что мне обратить внимание и в какую сторону вообще копать. Я новичок в джанго и он для меня весьма непрозрачен.

Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы и комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось нужно просто поменять `местами account_confirm_email` и `account_email_verification_sent`

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
            name='account_confirm_email'),
    re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
            name='account_email_verification_sent'),

]
```